# Creating setColor method without parameter being passed?

Tags: java, methods, setter

I'm working on a homework project for an intro to java course. To practice calling methods and organizing tasks, we have to create two balloon objects s1 and s2 and modify their colors and altitudes using methods in a separate java class.

I have everything working fine, but not exactly to the requirements of the assignment. The sheet lists the method declarations and they cannot be changed, only the code within them can.

The method that is used to change a balloon's color is to be created as `public void setColor()`. This doesn't make sense to me, though. I'm using `public void setColor(String color)` for now.

How can I change the color property of a balloon object without passing anything to the setColor method?

Comment: Hard code the color it's being changed to?

Comment: I'd say it's an error on the part of your instructor. I'd ask him/her directly if I were you.

Comment: Patrick, could you explain what you mean by "hard code"? I'm still pretty new to java.

RealSkeptic, that's possible but I thought I'd check first to see if I was missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @RealSkeptic but as your question says that changing the color without passing any value it means you need to generate the color each time your could use the following code. I'm not sure do this code is what you need.

```
public void setColor()
    {
        int red,green,blue;
        red = green = blue = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        int high = 255, low = 0;
        red = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        green = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        blue = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        color = new Color(red,green,blue);
        //set this color to your balloon
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't specify any particular color without a parameter in the method. You can hardcode so that the color changes.

```
class Baloon {

private String[] colors = {"blue", "red" , "green"};
private int index = 0;
private String currentColor = colors[index];

      public void setColor(){

      index ++;
      if (index = colors.length)
          index = 0;
      currentColor = colors[index]; 

      }
}
```

Comment: That definitely makes sense. Thanks!